# Why putchar, toupper, tolower, etc. take a int instead of a char?

Tags: c, putchar, tolower, toupper

In C, strings are arrays of char (`char *`) and characters are usually stored in `char`. I noticed that some functions from the libC are taking as argument integers instead of a char.

For instance, let's take the functions `toupper()` and `tolower()` that both use `int`. The man page says:

> If c is not an unsigned char value, or EOF, the behavior of these
>   functions is undefined.

My guess is that with a `int`, `toupper` and `tolower` are able to deal with `unsigned char` and `EOF`. But in fact `EOF` is in practice (is there any rule about its value?) a value that can be stored with a `char`, and since those functions won't transform `EOF` into something else, I'm wondering why `toupper` does not simply take a char as argument.

In any case why do we need to accept something that is not a character (such as EOF)? Could someone provide me a relevant use case?

This is similar with `fputc` or `putchar`, that also take a `int` that is converted into an `unsigned char` anyway.

I am looking for the precise motivations for that choice. I want to be convinced, I don't want to answer that I don't know if someone ask me one day.

Comment: I do not know any rule that `EOF` must fit into a `char`, and I can assure you that `char` is not guaranteed to be signed, which makes your discussion about using `char` instead of `unsigned char` seem the wrong one. You mean `signed char` throughout.

Comment: Did you look at implementations of these functions. I think `int` parameter is for optimization purposes, because its byte size well fit to sizes of the processor registers.  In turn, one byte `char` variable must be converted to `int` behind the curtain, and this operation need some processor time to process.

Comment: Read this: [Definition of EOF and how to use it effectively](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1048865140)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C11 7.4

> The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping
>   characters. In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the
>   macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is
>   undefined.

C11 7.21.1

> EOF
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a
>   negative value, ...

The C standard explicitly states that **EOF is always an int with negative value**. And furthermore, the signedness of the default `char` type is implementation-defined, so it may be unsigned and not able to store a negative value:

C11 6.2.5

> If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a char
>   object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative. If any other
>   character is stored in a char object, the resulting value is
>   implementation-defined but shall be within the range of values that
>   can be represented in that type.

Comment: One of my question is: why a function that converts a letter into another should accept something that is not a letter? (EOF included)

Comment: The other answer has answered your question (why a function like `tolower()` needs to accept something that is not a letter, e.g. `EOF`) -- because in the idiomatic case like `tolower(ch = getchar())`, `ch`, which is an `int`, might well be `EOF`, and thus it is desirable that `tolower` can accept `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

BITD a coding method included:

```
/* example */
int GetDecimal() {
  int sum = 0;
  int ch;
  while (isdigit(ch = getchar())) { /* isdigit(EOF) return 0 */
    sum *= 10;
    sum += ch - '0';
    }
  ungetc(ch, stdin);  /* If c is EOF, operation fails and the input stream is unchanged. */
  return sum;
}
```

`ch` with the value of EOF then could be used in various functions like `isalpha()` , `tolower()`.

This style caused problems with `putchar(EOF)` which I suspect did the same as `putchar(255)`.

The method is **discouraged today** for various reasons.  Various models like the following are preferred.

```
int GetDecimal() {
  int ch;
  while (((ch = getchar()) != EOF)) && isdigit(ch)) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I've +1 your answer for the example of use. But as you said, it is discouraged so why `isdigit` should accept something that is not a character?

Comment: @Maxime I am certain it is historical that `isdigit()` accepts `-1`.  Conceptually, it not hard to think of EOF as another `char`.  The `isthis...()` functions are often implemented with an 256 byte array, making a 257 byte array to also accept EOF (-1) is trivial.  Since its easy and makes for tighter code, back when tight code was of higher value, its a good extension.  Now, with code maintenance of every increasing value, this idiom has lost favor.

Answer (score 1):

*If c is not an unsigned char value, or EOF, the behavior of these functions is undefined.*

But `EOF` is a negative `int` in C and some platforms (hi ARM!) have `char` the same as `unsigned char`.

Comment: Yes, but in the places where it matters, the C standard says "unsigned char or EOF".