# toupper returns integer rather than char

Tags: c++, toupper

for the following function

```
void display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] < 84 && (i+j)%2 == 0)
                SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), 0x70);
            else if (board[i][j] < 84 && (i+j)%2 == 1)
                SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), 0xc0);
            else if (board[i][j] > 97 && (i+j)%2 == 0)
                SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), 0x7c);
            else if (board[i][j] > 97 && (i+j)%2 == 1)
                SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), 0xc7);
            cout << " " << toupper(board[i][j]) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

instead of returning chars for the char board[8][8] it returns integers so my output looks like

```
 82  78  66  81  75  66  78  82

 80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80 

 32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 

 32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 

 32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 

 32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32 

 80  80  80  80  80  80  80  80 

 82  78  66  81  75  66  78  82
```

rather than the expected output of

```
 R  N  B  Q  K  B  N  R

 P  P  P  P  P  P  P  P




 P  P  P  P  P  P  P  P

 R  N  B  Q  K  B  N  R
```

I have also tried declaring a char a = board[i][j]; cout << toupper(a); in an attempt to confirm the variable type as a character and received the same output.

this is an assignment for a class so i don't expect much help, i just want to know why my function is returning integers in place of chars so that i know what my mistake is for future reference, Google didn't help much. is it some sort of scope issue with toupper?

Comment: Have you tried casting the return value of `toupper`?

Comment: Why no google up first for reference?

Comment: If you just want a function that converts ASCII upper to ASCII lower characters, I suggest using (or writing) a function specific to this encoding. Such a function can then be type-safe, i.e. deal with `char`s instead of `int`s, and does not need to deal with locales (-> faster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toupper function returns the uppercase equivalent to c, if such value exists, or c (unchanged) otherwise. The value is returned as an int value that can be implicitly casted to char.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/

Comment: `EOF` however is an `int`, which may be passed to `toupper`, but may not be casted to a `char` (if `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)`).

Comment: instead of casting char a to board[i][j] i cast it directly into toupper(board[i][j]) and this seems to have skipped the step where the char is converted to an int, i think because I'm casting it to a char at the same time as I'm calling toupper so maybe it goes from char to int to char?

Comment: @dyp: Certainly the value of `EOF` can be converted to `char`. If `char` is unsigned, the result is well defined. If `char` is unsigned, the result is well defined as long as `EOF >= CHAR_MIN` (which it usually is). The result of such a conversion is not particularly useful, though. (Typically `EOF == -1`.)

Comment: by the way, thank you for explaining the return type of toupper to me rather than just giving me the code to fix my function, i think i understand toupper better now

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, I was alluding to `EOF < CHAR_MIN` in the case `char` is signed. Anyway, it seems this conversion is typically not injective?

Comment: Def: Implicit: *"Implied rather than expressly stated"*. There's nothing *implicit* about the cast required to perform the desired behavior of the OP. The cast required to send an `int` as  `char` to `std::cout` is *explicit* in order to invoke the proper overloaded `operator <<`. The text verbatim from cplusplus.com isn't exactly helpful in this particular case (is anyone surprised by that?), whether copied word-for-word here or on their site.

Answer (score 5):

The intention for toupper is that it can work in other languages than English, and hence it would have to support input and output which is larger than the 8 bit `char`, and therefor should return something which can be transformed into a unicode or UTF-character.

Simply just casting it to `char` is probably a source of buggy code for later on depending on what the purpose of your software is.

Have a look at this question on how to use it for wide characters and unicode.

[Convert a unicode String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991431/convert-a-unicode-string-in-c-to-upper-case)

Comment: C, §7.4 "The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases **the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`**. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined." That the parameter is not a `char` has nothing to do with Unicode. It probably has nothing to do with locales, either. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17452847 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5919735

Comment: You are quoteing "C" standard, but the question is about "C++", and the functions are reportedly working for std::wchar according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991431/convert-a-unicode-string-in-c-to-upper-case -- I have not tried this myself, and I have not looked up the C++ standard if the "undefined" behavior in C is defined in C++

Comment: Those are functions "imported" from the C Standard Library into C++. They are not explicitly defined for C++, but only via reference to the C Standard. `wchar_t` etc are not necessarily related to Unicode either. Since on typical implementations, an `unsigned char` can represent values in [0, 255], it cannot be used for e.g. UTF-8 directly.

Comment: As far as I can see from glancing over those answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991431/convert-a-unicode-string-in-c-to-upper-case they all DO NOT work reliably or properly. `wchar_t` in most \*nix systems has 32 bits and therefore *can* be used to store a Unicode code point / UTF-32 code unit. On Windows systems, it has 16 bits and is therefore not enough to contain a code point. Also, proper treatment e.g. of German ß is almost impossible: `BUSSE` can either be `buße` or `busse`, depending on what's meant; the former cannot be done on per-character basis.

Comment: *"Since on typical implementations, an unsigned char can represent values in [0, 255], it cannot be used for e.g. UTF-8 directly."* I have to qualify that: It can be used to *store* a UTF-8 code unit, but no additional information can be (portably) passed if you use it as a parameter type (like, other code units to form a code point).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `cout << char(toupper(board[i][j]));` to work around the goofy return type of toupper.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is clear : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/

```
int toupper ( int c );
```

So you just have to cast to `char`:

```
cout << " " << (char) toupper(board[i][j]) << " ";
```

Comment: Side remark: "The documentation" is just **a** documentation. It is not official.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't search the specification.

Comment: I see, so toupper converts to an integer value, my workaround was char a = toupper(board[i][j]); so i believe that the data type went char to int to char, but i think your solution would work better as it wouldn't require the creation of an unneeded variable