# Why is function 'lower' has int as return type and input type?

Tags: c, int

```
int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        printf("%c -> %c\n", s[i], lower(s[i]));
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int lower(int c)
{
    return (c >= 'A' && c<= 'Z') ? c + 'a' - 'A' : c;
}
```

This is the program to convert all the alphabets to lower case . So in the solution they used a lower function but I don't know why they used int as return type.

Comment: I could be wrong but I beleive this is because it will interpret it as ASCII Code instead of a characters

Comment: Because in C character literals aren't really `char` but `int`.

Comment: Do you mean `islower` or `tolower`? `lower` has a `return` type of `int` because you wrote it like that.

Comment: And note that your `lower` function may not work with other character encodings that are officially supported by C.

Comment: Note that the result of `lower()` as `int` or `char` would converted to `int` anyways as a `...` argument to `printf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is function 'lower' has int as return type and input type?

1. The code is entirely `int` math.  Even if the signature was `char c`, the code would have an `int` result due to the usual integer promotions.

   ```
   int lower(int c) {
     return (c >= 'A' && c<= 'Z') ? c + 'a' - 'A' : c;
   }
   ```
2. To map typically 257 different values like the `tolower()`.  With `int lower(char c) {` and `c < 0`, this could function differently than `tolower()`.
3. `int` is usually near the native processor integer size and code is *usually* tightest and fastest with `int` versus `char`.  This is a C historically choice and compromise.  Including original C did not prototype the function signature and all `int` and sub-`int` arguments were promoted to `int`.

**7.4 Character handling**

> The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping
>   characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the
>   argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined. C11dr §7.4 1

These `is...()` and `to...()` functions work in the `unsigned char range` (and `EOF`) and not `char`.

Robust code would avoid negative `char` when calling `tolower()` or `tolower()`-like functions.

```
// printf("%c -> %c\n", s[i], lower(s[i]));
printf("%c -> %c\n", s[i], lower((unsigned char) s[i]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Its most likely attempting to mimic the tolower function which uses int.

A similar question on tolower using an int is here.
[Why putchar, toupper, tolower, etc. take a int instead of a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452847/why-putchar-toupper-tolower-etc-take-a-int-instead-of-a-char)